# How to get text from a div or class via requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am writing a script that locates and prints the transaction amount of the most recent transaction at this website https://ltc.tokenview.io/en/address/M8T1B2Z97gVdvmfkQcAtYbEepune1tzGua

This is the code I am trying to use.

```
def getRecentTransaction(address):
    r = requests.get(f'https://ltc.tokenview.io/en/address/{address}')
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    amount = soup.find(class_="input_value")
    amountStuff = amount.text.strip()
    print(amountStuff)
```

However this is just returning "none". Now I am aware that there are multiple "input-value" classes on the website but when I did find all I got "[]". The only way I was able to retrieve the text was using selenium's by Xpath function. However, I am trying to write this so people can just input an address and then get the recent transaction amount. The Xpath method is too specific.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded with help of javascript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. To get the data you can do:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://ltc.tokenview.io/api/address/balancetrend/ltc/M8T1B2Z97gVdvmfkQcAtYbEepune1tzGua"

data = requests.get(api_url).json()

# print most recent:
print(data["data"][0])
```

Prints:

```
{'2024-01-06': '2504667.37296058'}
```

---

The most recent transaction:

```py
import re

import requests

url = "https://ltc.tokenview.io/en/address/M8T1B2Z97gVdvmfkQcAtYbEepune1tzGua"
html_text = requests.get(url).text

inp, out = re.search(r'value:"([^"]+).*?value:"([^"]+)', html_text).groups()
print(f"{inp=} {out=}")
```

Prints:

```
inp='0.02387814' out='0.02319739'
```